Comparing multiple values in a table makes it that it choses to compare only one randomly
I am making a tetris clone in love2d (lua) for practice. And what I am trying to do is to make the collins with the walls.
Note:the tetris pieces are made out of tiles that each one has a relative positions to the piece's position that is stored inside of a table.
Here's how I implemented the wall collisions
function tetros.wallLeftCollision(x)
  for i, c in pairs(tetros.shapes[v.shape].angles[v.angle].cubes) do
    local cx= c.x+x
    if cx-1 <= v.window.x then
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
end

x: is the piece's x position
"tetros.shapes[v.shape].angles[v.angle].cubes": is the table that contains the relative positions of the tiles that forms the piece
"cx= c.x+x": here I convert the relative position to a normal position
"cx-1" I just shift the position slightly to the left
"v.window.x" this is the x position of the space where the pices fall (idk how to call it)
But when I run the code it apparently choses a random tile and compare it instead of comparing all the tiles.
what should happen here is the code checks if the position of any tile in the tetris piece  is 1 pixel to the right pf the border and the it returns true.
After that I tried to do a bunch of research to see why it was happening but all I found is that it should work as it is.
Note:Please consider the fact that I have no programming experience beside Minecraft commands and I am just getting started

With a little more programming experience it will become clear to you that if a return is always executed in a loop, the loop body will never run more than once.

Normally, any collision checking is a loop:
(here block is a list of tiles, each tile is a table with x and y positions)
function detectCollision (movingBlock, staticBlock)
  for i, movingTile in ipairs (movingBlock) do
    for j, staticTile in ipairs (staticBlock) do
      if isColliding (movingTile, staticTile) then
        return true -- yes, at least one collision
      end
    end
  end
  return false -- no, there was no collision
end

For the movement you can just add extra dx and dy to check the collision by this movement:
function detectCollision (movingBlock, staticBlock, dx, dy)
  for i, movingTile in ipairs (movingBlock) do
    for j, staticTile in ipairs (staticBlock) do
      if isColliding (movingTile, staticTile, dx, dy) then
        return true -- yes, at least one collision
      end
    end
  end
  return false -- no, there was no collision
end

Example function to compare two tiles after movement to dx, dy:
function isColliding (movingTile, staticTile, dx, dy)
  if movingTile.x + dx == staticTile.x
  and movingTile.y + dy == staticTile.y then 
    return true -- same position of tiles means collision
  else
    return false -- no collision
  end
end

